# SqlException was unhandled error

Tags: c#, .net

[image][image]

I am getting

> SqlException was unhandled error

message when I run the program. bellow is all codes form my visual studio and also check attached image for error message screen shot.

Please help me to find how can I solve this problem. Where i am doing wrong?

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace LoginSystem
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Close();
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-V05BRHA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LoginSystem;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;");
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Tables where UserName='"+ textBox1.Text + "' and Password='" + textBox2.Text + "'",con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
                {

                this.Hide();
                Main ss = new Main();
                ss.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter your username and password");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Invalid object name 'Tables' - do you have Tables table in your database?

Comment: Sometime I wonder why someone wants to shoot itself in this way. Your table is named TABLE not TABLES. And now after fixing the typo, start asking why your code fails with a SYNTAX ERROR. Table is a reserved keyword. Could you rename your 'TABLE' to something more meaningful?

Comment: There are so many errors here that a full answer requires a blog article: A quick checklist 1) Tables instead of Table (the least of the problems), 2) Hardcoded connection string(will never work on other machines) 3) Pooling=false(Oh my god, why?) 4)String concatenation(Bobby Tables is happy to join the party) 5) Adapert fill to retrieve a scalar value?(useless performance hit) 6) Password in clear text?(Again hackers will be very happy with that)  7) Failing to dispose objects like the connection (System resources leak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Tables table in the database. Could you please modify you query from

```
Select Count(*) From Tables
```

to

```
Select Count(*) From Table
```

In addition, I would suggest to rename table to User or Login. It is better keep meaningful names of tables.